# post php variables to mobile site using javascript - blank variables

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, mobile

I want to redirect users to a mobile version of my website.

The redirect works fine, however the php variables are not passing.

I am using the following:

```
<script>
if ($(window).width() < 480 || $(window).height() < 480) {
var searchproducts = "<?php $_GET['search']?>";
var category = "<?php $_GET['cat']?>";

var page="http://m.website.com/search.php?search="+searchproducts+"&cat="+category;
document.location.href=page;

}
</script>
```

I have also tried:

```
<script>
if ($(window).width() < 480 || $(window).height() < 480) {
window.location.replace("http://m.website.com/search.php?search=<?php $_GET['search']?>&cat=<?php $_GET['cat']?>");

}
</script>
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `echo`statement..

```
var searchproducts = "<?php echo isset($_GET['search']) ? $_GET['search'] : 'Nothing'; ?>";
var category       = "<?php echo isset($_GET['cat']) ? $_GET['cat'] : 'Nothing'; ?>";
```

Also, use an `isset` construct as shown.

Comment: @user3312792, Also, use the `isset` construct to avoid `Undefined Index` notices.

Answer (score 0):

You are not echoing the variables. Like this:

```
<?php echo $_GET['cat']?>
```